# Difference between s. entsinnen, s. erinnern and s. besinnen

Tags: difference

What is the different between *sich entsinnen*, *sich erinnern* and *sich besinnen*?

- Do all of they mean *to remember*?
- In which context are they used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erinnen == Remember, Remind, Reflect

- s. entsinnen => to remember something
- s. erinnern => to be reminded about something
- s. besinnen => to reflect upon something

Answer (score 5):

**`entsinnen`** is used very seldom. It's an `old word for remember sth.` Look here for the flection of the word: 
 [duden-entsinnen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/entsinnen)

**`erinnern`**  is `remember` in German. You can use it the same way you would use remember in English (this is regarding to the meaning of both words. *Please have a look at the comment of Thorsten Dittmar*). Also it's manly used.
 [duden-erinnern](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erinnern)

**`besinnen`** is a bit more complicated. It's meaning is more about 'bring something back on ones mind'. That may be bad English but I am not able to give a single word for it's translation.
 Oh `reflect could be good translation`.
 [duden-besinnen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/besinnen)

"`besinnen`" is often used to say something like :`"Sich auf das Wesentliche besinnen"` which means something like: `"To focus on the important"` or `"to get back to basics"`.

**tl;dr**  `erinnern` is your best choice if you are not sure about what word to use.
entsinnen is an older term and seldom used in "common German".
Even in the examples of `besinnen` you could use `erinnern`. Like "Sich an das Wesentliche erinnern". That would be good German too. We also would use phrases like this.

Comment: It should be stretched here that in German *erinnern* is a reflexive verb. You need to say *ich erinnere **mich** an etwas*, not *ich erinnere etwas*. This is used in some regional dialects, but is actually not correct. Thus *You can use it the same way you would use remember in English* is true when it comes to the meaning, but wrong when it comes to grammar.