# Niveau von "Wenn ich mich recht besinne/entsinne/erinnere"

Tags: difference, usage

> (a) Wenn ich mich recht **besinne**, waren wir schon einmal hier.
>
> (b) Wenn ich mich recht **entsinne**, waren wir schon einmal hier.
>
> (c) Wenn ich mich recht **erinnere**, waren wir schon einmal hier.

Ich glaube, alle drei Sätze bedeuten genau dasselbe. Aber gibt es Unterschiede in dem Niveau? In welcher Situation würde man jeden verwenden?

Comment: Be/entsinnen sind verschieden.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Auch im gegebenen Kontext? Bitte erklären ...

Comment: Related: [Difference between s. entsinnen, s. erinnern and s. besinnen](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8769/difference-between-s-entsinnen-s-erinnern-and-s-besinnen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So wie viele andere Wörter können auch *erinnern, besinnen* und *entsinnen* unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben, sodass sie nicht unbedingt gegeneinander ausgetauscht werden können. In Duden – *Deutsches Universalwörterbuch* werden die folgenden Bedeutungen genannt:

> **erinnern**
>   **1.** *im Gedächtnis bewahrt haben und sich dessen wieder bewusst werden*
>   **2. a)** *die Erinnerung an jemanden, etwas bei jemandem wachrufen; wieder ins Bewusstsein rufen*
>   **b)** *veranlassen, an etwas zu denken, jemanden, etwas nicht zu vergessen*
>   **c)** *durch seine Ähnlichkeit ins Bewusstsein bringen*
>   **3.** (veraltend) *vorbringen, zu bedenken geben*
>
> **besinnen**
>   **1.** *nachdenken, überlegen*
>   **2. a)** *sich an jemanden, etwas erinnern*
>   **b)** *sich bewusst werden*
>   **3.** *bedenken, über etwas nachsinnen*
>
> **entsinnen**
>   *sich etwas wieder ins Gedächtnis rufen; sich erinnern*

Speziell der in der Frage genannte Ausdruck ist allerdings mit allen drei Verben möglich. In Duden – *Das Stilwörterbuch* findet man die entsprechenden Beispiele:

> wenn ich mich recht erinnere, war er vor fünf Jahren hier
>
> wenn ich mich recht besinne, war sie schon einmal hier
>
> wenn ich mich recht entsinne, …

Das Verb *entsinnen* ist dort explizit als gehoben gekennzeichnet. Allerdings ist sicherlich auch das Verb *besinnen* gehobener als das gewöhnliche *erinnern.*

Laut [duden.de](http://www.duden.de/) kommt [*erinnern*](http://www.duden.de/node/754522/revisions/1299407/view) häufiger vor als [*besinnen*](http://www.duden.de/node/659253/revisions/1302326/view) und das wiederum häufiger als [*entsinnen*](http://www.duden.de/node/807295/revisions/1268390/view). Dabei wird jedoch nicht zwischen den verschiedenen Bedeutungen unterschieden.